# Gutenberg-Richter Recurrence Law: why is rate defined as probability of being exceeded?

Tags: regression, probability, survival, extreme-value, exponential-distribution

According to Kramer (1996): Guttenberg and Richter gathered data for Southern California earthquakes over a period of many years and organized data according to the number of earthquakes that exceeded different magnitudes during that time of period. Then, t**hey divided the number of exceedances of each magnitude by the length of time period** to define a mean annual rate of exceedance, $\lambda_m$ of an earthquake of magnitude m. When the logarithm of the mean annual rate was plotted against earthquake magnitude, a linear relationship was observed

$log \lambda_m =a-bm$

The equation may also be expressed as
$\lambda_m = e^{\alpha - \beta m}$
where $\alpha=2.303a$ and $\beta=2.303b$. It implies that earthquake magnitudes are exponentially distributed.

Refference: Kramer, S. L. (1996). Geotechnical Earthquake Engineering. Chapter 4 Page 121-123

**Question:**

The right hand side of the last equation can be expressed as

$e^{\alpha - \beta m}=e^{-\beta(m-\alpha/\beta)}$

So I guess the right hand side is actually the exceedance probability of exponential distribution $X$, where $X=m-\alpha/\beta$. But I'm a bit confused with the left hand side, **since $\lambda$ is rate (not a probability)**. Anything I missed?

Comment: Is $\lambda_m$ the rate of earthquakes with magnitude $m$ or the rate of earthquakes with magnitude $\geq m$? In the second case, it would just be *thinning* a Marked Poisson process.

Comment: @Yves $\lambda_m$  is the rate of earthquakes with magnitude ≥m